# Can deep link be handled in iOS using MSAL?

Tags: ios, azure-active-directory, azure-mobile-services, azure-ad-b2c

The authorization response URL is returned to the app via the iOS openURL app delegate method and [MSALPublicClientApplication handleMSALResponse:url]; is called. However when a URL has deeplink will SFSafariViewController redirect to the app as well? If not, how to handle deeplink? If deep link cannot be handled using MSAL is there anyway to take control over SFSafariViewController to obtain the URI(or URL) the browser gets navigated to?

Comment: If not, how to handle deeplink? If deep link cannot be handled using MSAL is there anyway to take control over SFSafariViewController to obtain the URI(or URL) the browser gets navigated to? -- is not clear

Comment: If MSAL has no provision to handle SFSafariViewController actions through its library then how to handle deep linking in MSAL? @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: whats your iOS verson, it is possible to handle the SFSafariViewController cookies but recently apple has stopped the process from iOS 11 onwards, if you google it once related to the name of `attribution tracking`

Comment: Coding for iOS 11 too. @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: if you used this the apple will reject your app, but local purpose you can use `SFAuthenticationSession` for get the details, but the information no longer available for catch the attribution

Comment: if once its reached the app you can handle outside the app you can't handle

Comment: What is the experience you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm using MSAL in my iOS app, I've created tenant, scopes, etc and i'm able to work on it. However i've to handle a navigation such that when I hit on it, it should transfer the control to my native app.